# Integrating facebook to android app

Tags: android, facebook

I have a simple question here. What is the need for integrating FB sdk to android app.

I can open the facebook url in web view and login and do whatever to be done on FB. Then  what will be the scenario where FB need to be integrated with my app .

Comment: http://www.android10.org/index.php/articleslibraries/290-facebook-integration-in-your-android-application , http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/

Comment: i understood how to do , my question is what is the scenario . without integrating , i can open FB url and like /post .

Comment: please let me know the reason for downvoting this question. I was trying to understand if i need to integrate FB to my app or can just do with links and save the size of my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Facebook sdk, you can upload photos directly to your Facebook albums, and also you can get all the user likes, friends and many more.

Compared to work with webview, the use of sdk saves time for your app user - he don't need to login every time he want's to enter his profile (Using sso - Single Sign On) or any other thing, that requires Facebook.

In my case, I activate the native Facebook app directly from my app, with my app page. In my opinion, if you don't need something more sophisticated, just showing page, you can use it.

In case there is no native Facebook app, activate it with the user browser (catch block).

```
try{

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://profile/" + PROFILE_FACEBOOK_APP_ID));
startActivity(intent);

}catch(Exception e){

startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com/UserNamePage")));
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer . Few quries : as per FB dev, sso doesnt work, so even if we integrate , we have to sign on first time. And if i open my page by link and if i do not explicitly sign off, i dont have to sign in agai. SO i dont see any difference on that point. Do you agree with this. I agree with other points.

Comment: @preetha I agree with that point, but I can tell you SSO is much more user friendly. The user need to authorize that you can access his profile, and also to do what you want to do, like see his likes. In these days, privacy gets more and more familiar, and users wants to know what your application can get from their personal stuff. So SSO, is much more preferable than a webview.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the integration is used when the developer wants to post on a users' behalf, add pictures directly to specified albums, get a user's email address etc.

These can be done when the user authorises the app for the first time, they also authorise the privileges.

It is also seen as a marketing tool, as all the posts will say via (yourAppName), so you can gain some online presence.

Like Ofir A said, it is time saving for the user as they only need to log in once.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Why you are calling webview with facebook link.You should use FaceBook Native Sdk for Android.This giveing your better user experience compare to webview. [Refrence for Facebook Integration](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#register)

Comment: i am trying to understand why cant i use the simplle solution